# WP7 :before and :after

Tags: css, windows-phone-7, pseudo-element

I have searched the web a while and I can't find the answer to my question.

Does WP7 support pseudo-elements like `:before` and `:after`?

Does anyone have the answer to this question or can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone 7.0 runs IE Mobile 7 which uses Trident 3.1 (IE's layout engine) which corresponds to a combination of IE7 and IE8 on the desktop. It's not clear whether this means the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements are supported, though. [Wikipedia seems to subtly hint at the contrary.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_%28layout_engine%29)

Windows Phone 7.5 "Mango" runs IE Mobile 9 (there is no IE Mobile 8) which uses Trident 5.0 which corresponds to IE9 on the desktop, so you can at least expect support on IE in that version.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone v. 7.5 (Mango) runs what is essentially IE9. So you can expect pretty decent support of CSS3. Older versions run a weird browser that falls somewhere around IE8 levels of compatability.